# How to push data to client's server

Tags: java, web-services

We have a system in place which collects data from multiple sensors and stores the data into the database, we have a website where our customers can log in and view their data.

Now one of our customers wants to display the data from our server into their web site.
I created a web service and gave them access to collect the data from the our database and import it into their website, but they are requesting us to push the data to their server.
I am not sure how this can be done! Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Ask them to create a webservice and you call it.

Comment: If they did not specify what they mean by "push" Nambari is correct.  The other low tech option is just to export it and send if via FTP.

Comment: Is there any way I can push my data to their website, somthing like Pushlets. I think they don't want to do anything on their end :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot push your data to any other server unless you have remote access to their server. You can either ask them to provide you the remote access to their database and write a service to push your data into their server or database . Or you can work out with your client to design a mechanism where their website would call you web service to display you data into their website.

[Ajax-Push-Engine](http://ape-project.org/) project could be useful in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing that you're trying to do a year ago. Apart from viewing the data at the client's side, I also displayed an almost real-time graph where the graph would be updated after a specific interval of time set by you (I set it as 1 second). The real-time data transmission thing was handled by PubNub framework. You can go through my implementation on GitHub below.

[RealTime Arduino Sensor Data Visualization](https://github.com/UtkarshGpta/realtime-arduino-sensor-data)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think your client want you to **export** their data with you and put it on their servers. Copy whatever sensor data they wish to have, give it away as a deliverable unit. Modify your webservice code to be called from and through their web server. It is almost like finishing up the project.